# ArrayList Not Replying Proper Result in jsp Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Following is my java code, where arraylist not replying proper result.

### Proper Result [Should Display on screen]

2016/04
2016/05
2016/06
2016/07
2016/08
2016/09
2016/10
2016/11
2016/12
2017/01
2017/02
2017/03
2017/04
2017/05
2017/06
2017/07
2017/08
2017/09

### But Result Appearing

v_p_DataCont@183d59c
v_p_DataCont@3cfaab
v_p_DataCont@16d3046
v_p_DataCont@17c4779
v_p_DataCont@3861e6
v_p_DataCont@1a37fac
v_p_DataCont@1132e76
v_p_DataCont@4f71a3
v_p_DataCont@1ad9b0f
v_p_DataCont@9effe0
v_p_DataCont@b101cf
v_p_DataCont@edf4c8
v_p_DataCont@61a414
v_p_DataCont@5b55a9
v_p_DataCont@54f169
v_p_DataCont@b524aa
v_p_DataCont@7a3a30
v_p_DataCont@825cf3

### rnssp-report1.jsp

```
<html>
<style>
label
{
width: 23em;
float: left;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0em;
color: red;
background: #FFFF00;
display: block
}

.submit input
{
margin-left: 2.5em;
} 
input
{
color: #781351;
background: #fee3ad;
border: 1px solid #781351
}
.submit input
{
margin-left: 0em;
color: #000;
background: #ffa20f;
border: 2px outset #d7b9c9
}
fieldset
{
margin-left: 10.5em;
border: 1px solid #781351;
width: 60em
}
legend
{
margin-left: 20.5em;
color: #fff;
background: #ffa20c;
border: 1px solid #781351;
padding: 2px 6px
}
</style>
    <head>
        <title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <%
     String action="v_p_Search1";
     String method="get";
     String method1="post";
    %>


    <form name="myForm1"  method= "<%=method%>" action="<%=action%>">

    <h1><center><color : blue> YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</center></h1>
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Please Input Voucher Period</legend>
 <br />
 <p>
 <label for="name">Click on Search Button Bellow To Select Voucher Period</label>
 </p>
 <br />
 <p class="submit">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" action="#{v_p_Search1.get}">
 </p>
</fieldset>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### v_p_Search1.java

```
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.Console;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.lang.String;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class v_p_Search1 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


String t_date_year = " ";
int t_date_year_n = 0;
int t_date_year_n1 = 0;
String inp_year_mon = " ";
String s_date1 = "          ";
String s_date2 = "          ";
String Field1 = " ";

             DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
             Date s_date = new Date();
             s_date1 = (dateFormat2.format(s_date)); 
             s_date2 = s_date1.substring(0, 11); 
             t_date_year = s_date2.substring(0, 4);
             t_date_year_n=Integer.parseInt(t_date_year);
             t_date_year_n1 = t_date_year_n - 1;
             inp_year_mon =  t_date_year_n1+"/04";

        List<v_p_DataCont> list=v_p_DataAction.getSelectedVouPeriod(inp_year_mon); 


            request.setAttribute("vpList", list);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchview1.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

        out.close();  
    }  
}
```

### v_p_DataAction.java

```
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.Console;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.lang.String;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Date;   
import java.text.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*; 

public class v_p_DataAction {  

            public static Connection getConnection(){  
            Connection con=null; 

        try{  
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");  
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@00.000.0.000:0000:xxx","yyyy", "zzzz");
           }
            catch(Exception e)
            {System.out.println(e);}  
             return con;  
                                                    }



    public static List<v_p_DataCont> getSelectedVouPeriod(String inp_year_mon){  
        List<v_p_DataCont> list=new ArrayList<v_p_DataCont>();


           try{
                 Connection con=v_p_DataAction.getConnection();  

                   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT X.Voucher_Period FROM com_agent_comm_dtl X where X.Voucher_Period >= '" + inp_year_mon + "' group by X.VOUCHER_PERIOD ORDER BY X.VOUCHER_PERIOD");
                   ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                   while (rs.next()) {
                       v_p_DataCont s=new v_p_DataCont();
                             s.setVoucher_Period(rs.getString(1));
                             list.add(s); 
                                     }


                           con.close();

              }
             catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}


           return list; 

                                                         }
}
```

### v_p_DataCont.java

```
public class v_p_DataCont {  
private String voucher_period;  

public String getVoucher_Period() {  
    return voucher_period;  
                                  }  
public void setVoucher_Period(String voucher_period) {  
    this.voucher_period = voucher_period;  
                                                     }

}
```

### web.xml

following part added in web.xml

```
<!-- JSPC servlet mappings start -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>v_p_Search1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>v_p_Search1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>v_p_Search1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v_p_Search1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>rnssp-report1.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSPC servlet mappings end -->
```

### searchview1.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="1000px" align="center"
               style="border:1px solid #000000;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan=16 align="center"
                    style="background-color:teal">
                    <b>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgrey;">
                <td><b>Voucher Period</b></td>
            </tr>
            <td>
            <select name="database1">
            <option value="" selected>select</option>
            <%

                String color = "#F9EBB3";
                if (request.getAttribute("vpList") != null) {
                        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("vpList");
                            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                            String Field=list.get(i).toString();


            %>
             <option value="<%=Field %>"><%=Field %></option>


            <%
                    }
                }
            %>
                </select>
              </td>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please Help Me, How Proper Result will appear in searchview1.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You should override `toString()` method in `v_p_DataCont` class

add this following code in `v_p_DataCont` class

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
return voucher_period;
}
```